# Get order info by id in Opencart Cms

Tags: php, e-commerce, opencart

It's possible to retrieve order info (such as name, price, etc) by order id? I want to replicate confirm table in checkout/checkout to checkout/success.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking in the `catalog/model/checkout/order.php` Order model you will find a method `getOrder()` accepting a mandatory parameter `$order_id`.

So yes, it is possible to get the order data by it's ID, simply by calling this line(s) somewhere in your controller:

```php
$this->load->model('checkout/order'); // call this only if this model is not yet instantiated!
$this->model_checkout_order->getOrder($orderId); // use the desired $orderId here
```

Comment: how can we get the complete total of order including tax and shipping?

Comment: This should be posted as new question. But what about taking a look into the mentioned Model and trying to figure out (by checking the available methods)?